# Выровнять текст в TextArea

Tags: javafx, текст

**Задача:** Имеется TextArea. Необходимо чтобы текст внутри выравнивался по центру, как по горизонтали так и вертикали.

**Проблема:** В классе TextArea отсутствуют методы отвечающие за выравнивание текста. Выравнивание с помощью  CSS (`text.setStyle("-fx-font-alignment: center;")`) не дает результата.

**Вопрос:** Возможно ли выровнять текст по центру в TextArea? Если да, то как? Если нет, то назовите пожалуйста альтернативные многострочные редактируемые текстовые поля.

Answer (score -1):

Вот так должно помочь

```
textarea {text-align:center;}
```